# How can make my function rotate 360 and move up and down?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, web-scripting

Hey guys so I'm working on animating my java script for a project, and being  a newbie at java-script I have only figured out how to make my image move up and down in a set area. How can make my object "dank" also spin 360 infinitly whiles using the following code to move it up and down? Any help is appreciated!

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {         
function myMove() {
   var elem = document.getElementById("dank");
   var pos = 100;
   var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
   function frame() {
        pos += 0.3;
        elem.style.top = pos + "px";
             if (Math.abs(pos) >= 250){
                   pos = 100;
                }
                frame();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`elem.style.transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to rotate text. If you assign degrees to a number it'd be something like:

`elem.style.transform = "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)"`

Also you should remove "frame();", you don't need it because setInterval(frame, 10) already calls the function over and over. Having it in there might cause some recursion problems.

Comment: Thanks much I really appreciate it!